# ggplot2 not present in rpy2 for python?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, ggplot2, rpy2

I am working with rpy2 v2.1.9 in Python3.2, I don't understand why I can't use the library ggplot2

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import r
r.library("ggplot2")
```

Here is the error message I got

```
Error in function (package, help, pos = 2, lib.loc = NULL, character.only = FALSE,  : 
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
     return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 34, in __call__
     res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
 rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in function (package, help, pos = 2, lib.loc = NULL, character.only = FALSE,  : 
   there is no package called 'ggplot2'
```

Comment: I am surprised that rpy2 2.1.9 and Python 3.2 are playing well together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the tail of the first error message:

> there is no package called 'ggplot2'

You need to install the `ggplot2` package first.  Fire up R itself, and say

```
 install.packages("ggplot2")
```

Comment: Thanks!! I thought that it was possible to directly install libraries from R via rpy2, now it's working.

Comment: Sure, you execute the command `install.package()` from `rpy2` -- and make sure you supply enough arguments (default mirror etc) to not require the pop-up.  This is very clearly scriptable, from R and/or Python via rpy2.

Comment: Is there a good reason to "fire up R" if using Jupyter Notebook or is there an equivalent package in Python?