# Trouble importing R libraries in python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am new in exploiting R codes in python using rpy2 module. I want to call `lofactor` function from `DMwR` library. I installed `DMwR` library in R using:

```
install.packages('DMwR')
```

But, in the python environment, it says that there is `no package called 'DMwR'`. I used two approach to `import DMwR`:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r.library("DMwR")
```

AND

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr("utils")
```

and got the same problem in both scenarios.

Comment: See this similar question [ggplot2 not present in rpy2 for python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7529862)

Comment: @BhargavRao : the inability to import `utils` indicates a more serious issue, I think. `utils` is part of R's "base" libraries (that should be present in any R installation).

Comment: @lgautier I have no idea about that :-( ... I saw a similar question only so I posted a comment. Regards :-)

Comment: There is something going on with the way R was installed (and we know nothing about it, not even the OS you are on), the way rpy2 was installed, or the environment in which you are running Python.

Comment: If you use Anaconda it installs its own R within the Anaconda folder which may not contain libraries. I have not used rpy2 but encountered the same problem when tried to call R from a Python script using `subprocess`. In my case the solution was to explicitly specify the R folder where my R was installed along with the R libraries.